# How to make a table display rows in two columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table that currently looks like this:

[image]

I need to use CSS to make the table rows display as two columns, so it looks like this:
[image]

(The font style/border width does not need to change)

However, I can't edit any of the HTML, as I do not have access to it. I can only alter the CSS.

I found this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp) on W3 Schools which shows how to make a two-column layout using flexbox properties. So I applied it to my table as follows:

```
table {
  display:block;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  flex:50%;
}
```

But it doesn't seemed to have worked. It just stays in one column. I have made a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/big_smile_pen/pen/PoREJGo).

Any ideas how I can make the table go into two columns (it doesn't have to be via flexbox but it should only be via CSS as I can't change the HTML).

Please note: This project will not be a website, but actually printed out as a PDF. So I am not too bothered about best practices for compatibility with multiple browsers or mobile etc. Because the final output will be PDF. Normally I would just use DTP software to sort out the layout. But in those case, there's too many entries. So if I can do the layout at the CSS level that will be better.

Comment: For the authors of the answers below, what if there are header cells <tr><th>title</th></tr>?

Comment: Why is an HTML table used in place of a `<ol>`? I know you cannot change the HTML, but it really should be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works at width: 40%; as well. You can add table {margin: auto;} to center it if you want. For tr, it is ok to replace float with display: inline-block. Hope it helps. Thanks

```
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    tr {
       float: left;
       width: 50%;
       border: 1px solid black;
    }

    tbody:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solutions

### CSS Grid (preferred)

Since every `<tr>` only ever has one `<td>`, you can simply use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```css
tbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}

/* Borders */
/* The margin declarations are used to simulate border-collapse:collapse */
tr {
  margin: 0 0 -1px -1px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody:not(:empty) {
  margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Abel Obrien</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Marylou Kelley</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Dusty Banks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4. Marcellus Richard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5. Elvin Porter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6. Savannah Mullen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7. Edna Bean</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8. Carson Larsen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9. Kelli Mack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10. Valeria Harding</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### More general solution

If the rows could have included more than one `<td>` each, you would (probably) have to resort to [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#contents):

```css
tbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}
tr {display: contents}

/* Borders */
td {
  margin: 0 0 -1px -1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody:not(:empty) {
  margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Some Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Other Example</td>
      <td>3. A third Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4. Yet another Example</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note**: In the example with `display: contents`, we lose the default styles (namely the padding) of the rows because we are now declaring the border to the data cells instead of the rows.

### CSS Flex

We can also use [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to lay out the cells.

**Note**: **Use CSS Grid** for grid-like results, and CSS Flexbox for flow-like results. You seem to expect a grid-like result.

Declaring `tbody` to be a flex parent (with allowed wrapping) gives us a flow-like result:

```css
tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Borders */
tr {
  margin: 0 0 -1px -1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody:not(:empty) {
  margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Abel Obrien</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Marylou Kelley</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Dusty Banks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4. Marcellus Richard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5. Elvin Porter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6. Savannah Mullen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7. Edna Bean</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8. Carson Larsen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9. Kelli Mack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10. Valeria Harding</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now we can try to force this flow-like result into a grid-like, 2-column layout (which CSS Flexbox is not intended for; **use CSS Grid** if you want a grid-like result):

- Using `calc()`:

```css
tr {
  width: calc(
    50%
    - 1px /* Subtract the overlappable border side */
  );
}

tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Borders */
tr {
  margin: 0 0 -1px -1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody:not(:empty) {
  margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Extensively long name that may or may not fit within this cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Marylou Kelley</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Dusty Banks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4. Marcellus Richard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5. Elvin Porter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6. Savannah Mullen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7. Edna Bean</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8. Carson Larsen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9. Kelli Mack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10. Valeria Harding</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- Using `flex`:

```css
tr {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Subtracts both border-sides */
  flex-grow: 1; /* Adds the non-overlappable border-side */
}
tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Borders */
tr {
  margin: 0 0 -1px -1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody:not(:empty) {
  margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Extensively long name that may or may not fit within this cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Marylou Kelley</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Dusty Banks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4. Marcellus Richard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5. Elvin Porter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6. Savannah Mullen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7. Edna Bean</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8. Carson Larsen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9. Kelli Mack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10. Valeria Harding</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Regarding W3 Schools' trick

The reason why the W3 Schools "2 column" trick doesn't work is because it requires a specific HTML structure. More specifically, it requires the two columns to be the only children in a wrapper. Each such column would have to already contain the children to lay out.

In your HTML, the `<td>` elements are the elements we want to lay out in the end. Because every `<tr>` element only contains one `<td>` element, they can effectively be treated as the elements we want to lay out.

These `<td>` elements we want to lay out (and therefore their `<tr>` parent elements) are only contained in a single table section (`<tbody>`), not in multiple distinct "column" elements. This means, translating W3 Schools' trick to your HTML does not work, because the HTML structure is fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

All it takes is flex on the parent `tbody`, and making its children (`tr`) width 50%.

```css
tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

tr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}


/* borders */

table {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Abel Obrien</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Marylou Kelley</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Dusty Banks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4. Marcellus Richard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5. Elvin Porter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6. Savannah Mullen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7. Edna Bean</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8. Carson Larsen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9. Kelli Mack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10. Valeria Harding</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```