# How to "wrap" a table into multiple columns?

Tags: html, css

My question is similar to [How to make a table display rows in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73184993/6607497), but actually *even more simple*:

I want a long, but narrow table to wrap into two columns (when the media has enough space), but the original ordering of rows should be preserved (that's the difference from the question cited).

I searched a lot, and I tried a lot, but I couldn't get it working (while it seems it must be easy).

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Cell A1</td><td>Cell B1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A2</td><td>Cell B2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A3</td><td>Cell B3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A4</td><td>Cell B4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A5</td><td>Cell B5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A6</td><td>Cell B6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A7</td><td>Cell B7</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A8</td><td>Cell B8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell A9</td><td>Cell B9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or maybe re-phrase the question:
Why doesn't it work when I put the table in a `<div>` that has style `column-count: 2` (and some little more tweaking)?

In a text processor like LibreOffice Writer I can define a region with two columns, and the a table inside wraps nicely.

### Illustration

Here's an example from LibreOffice Writer to illustrate what I mean (as some got a wrong idea, it seems):

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice Writer showing text with a two-column-table inside a two-column region]

### Actual sample

Here is an actual demo sample I'm trying to fix.
Sorry, but it's lengthy.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>(Test)</title>
    <style type="text/css">/*><!--*/
legend { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold }
div.supplier { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold }
div.supplier-notes { font-style: italic }
div.offering { column-count: 2 }
div.offering-notes { font-style: italic }
fieldset { display: inline-block }
span.button-spacer { display: inline-block; width: 2mm }
table#offering { border-style: none; border-width: thin }
th { text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif; }
td.numeric { text-align: right } 
table#offering tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #ccc }
tfoot { font-weight: bolder }
/**/-->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="supplier">Test</div>
    <div class="supplier-notes">
      <supplier.notes>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
      </supplier.notes>
    </div>
    <div class="offering">
      <form>
    <fieldset class="offering">
      <legend>Angebot / Bestellung</legend>
      <table id="offering">
        <thead>
          <tr id="item.header"><th>Beschreibung</th><th>Preis</th><th>Prod-Nr.</th><th>Anzahl</th><th>Summe</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="item-0"><td>ABC-Wärme Hansaplast...</td><td class="numeric">1,23</td><td class="numeric">111</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-1"><td>Kamillin extern</td><td class="numeric">12,34</td><td class="numeric">222</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-2"><td>ASS (Aspirin protect)</td><td class="numeric">3,21</td><td class="numeric">11</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-3"><td>ASS (Aspirin) plus</td><td class="numeric">3,33</td><td class="numeric">1234</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-0"><td>ABC-Wärme Hansaplast...</td><td class="numeric">1,23</td><td class="numeric">111</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-1"><td>Kamillin extern</td><td class="numeric">12,34</td><td class="numeric">222</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-2"><td>ASS (Aspirin protect)</td><td class="numeric">3,21</td><td class="numeric">11</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-3"><td>ASS (Aspirin) plus</td><td class="numeric">3,33</td><td class="numeric">1234</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-0"><td>ABC-Wärme Hansaplast...</td><td class="numeric">1,23</td><td class="numeric">111</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-1"><td>Kamillin extern</td><td class="numeric">12,34</td><td class="numeric">222</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-2"><td>ASS (Aspirin protect)</td><td class="numeric">3,21</td><td class="numeric">11</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
          <tr id="item-3"><td>ASS (Aspirin) plus</td><td class="numeric">3,33</td><td class="numeric">1234</td><td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td><td class="numeric result" ></td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr><td colspan="3">Summen</td><td class="numeric result" id="num-total">0</td><td class="numeric result" id="sum-total">0</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Summieren" onclick="sum_items()">
      <span class="button-spacer"></span>
      <input type="button" value="Drucken" onclick="print_items()">
    </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="offering-notes">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables are notoriously difficult to make responsive, you might consider using a css grid instead

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why did you remove tags?

Comment: `multiple-columns` as a tag does not fit here. Also, you should not tag in the title. What is it that you actually intend to do? Tables are for displaying tabular data. wrapping a table from 2-columns to a single column does not make much sense if you really want to display tabular data. My assumption is, that you misusing the table for layout purposes. So what is it that you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: wrapping that table inside a div having `column-count: 2;` will actually split the table in two parts. the flow of the table will have vertical priority and then will continue on the next column. Isn't exactly what you were trying to achieve? why you said it doesnt work?? or did you mean to have a different layout where the flow follows as [r1,r2][r3,r4][r5,r6] instead of [r1,r4][r2,r5][r3,r6]?

Comment: @tacoshy You seem to mis-understand the question. Maybe read again more slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Using tables, thead, tfoot, seems very unstable, but here's the sample:
All I did was target the tbody, and use some `display: block` on thead and tfoot.

```css
legend {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold
}

div.supplier {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold
}

div.supplier-notes {
  font-style: italic
}

div.offering {
  
}

div.offering-notes {
  font-style: italic
}

fieldset {
  display: block
}

span.button-spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2mm
}

table#offering {
  border-style: none;
  border-width: thin
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

td.numeric {
  text-align: right
}

table#offering tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #ccc
}

tfoot {
  font-weight: bolder
}

table thead {
  display: block;
}

table tbody {
 display: block;
 column-count: 2;
}

table tfoot {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="supplier">Test</div>
<div class="supplier-notes">
  <supplier.notes>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  </supplier.notes>
</div>
<div class="offering">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="offering">
      <legend>Angebot / Bestellung</legend>
      <table id="offering">
        <thead>
          <tr id="item.header">
            <th>Beschreibung</th>
            <th>Preis</th>
            <th>Prod-Nr.</th>
            <th>Anzahl</th>
            <th>Summe</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="item-0">
            <td>ABC-Wärme Hansaplast...</td>
            <td class="numeric">1,23</td>
            <td class="numeric">111</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-1">
            <td>Kamillin extern</td>
            <td class="numeric">12,34</td>
            <td class="numeric">222</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-2">
            <td>ASS (Aspirin protect)</td>
            <td class="numeric">3,21</td>
            <td class="numeric">11</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-3">
            <td>ASS (Aspirin) plus</td>
            <td class="numeric">3,33</td>
            <td class="numeric">1234</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-0">
            <td>ABC-Wärme Hansaplast...</td>
            <td class="numeric">1,23</td>
            <td class="numeric">111</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-1">
            <td>Kamillin extern</td>
            <td class="numeric">12,34</td>
            <td class="numeric">222</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-2">
            <td>ASS (Aspirin protect)</td>
            <td class="numeric">3,21</td>
            <td class="numeric">11</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-3">
            <td>ASS (Aspirin) plus</td>
            <td class="numeric">3,33</td>
            <td class="numeric">1234</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-0">
            <td>ABC-Wärme Hansaplast...</td>
            <td class="numeric">1,23</td>
            <td class="numeric">111</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-1">
            <td>Kamillin extern</td>
            <td class="numeric">12,34</td>
            <td class="numeric">222</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-2">
            <td>ASS (Aspirin protect)</td>
            <td class="numeric">3,21</td>
            <td class="numeric">11</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="item-3">
            <td>ASS (Aspirin) plus</td>
            <td class="numeric">3,33</td>
            <td class="numeric">1234</td>
            <td class="numeric"><input value="0" type="number"></td>
            <td class="numeric result"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Summen</td>
            <td class="numeric result" id="num-total">0</td>
            <td class="numeric result" id="sum-total">0</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Summieren" onclick="sum_items()">
      <span class="button-spacer"></span>
      <input type="button" value="Drucken" onclick="print_items()">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="offering-notes">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you edited the question with an illustration. Let me revise this.